# split long line on a delimiter

Tags: shell, text-processing

What command can I use to split input like this:

```
foo:bar:baz:quux
```

into this?

```
foo
bar
baz
quux
```

I'm trying to figure out the `cut` command but it seems to only work with fixed amounts of input, like "first 1000 characters" or "first 7 fields".  I need to work with arbitrarily long input.

Comment: You mean like `tr : '\n' < input`?

Comment: What shell are you using? bash?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are a few options:

- `tr : \\n`
- `sed 's/:/\n/g'` (with GNU sed)
- `awk '{ gsub(":", "\n") } 1'`

You can also do this in pure `bash`:

```
while IFS=: read -ra line; do
    printf '%s\n' "${line[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Note that using `\n` in the replacement string like that will work in GNU sed, but will fail in most other sed implementations.

Comment: @chrisdown Is there a way to get the first two to work in AIX?

Comment: `awk '{ gsub(":", "\n") } 1'` What does the `1` at the end do?

Comment: @Roland It's a condition without an action, which invokes the default action, which is to print `$0`.

Answer (score 5):

If your grep supports `-o` you can do it like this:

```
grep -o '[^:]\+'
```

Or with awk, setting the record separator to `:`:

```
awk -v RS=: 1
```

Or with GNU cut:

```
cut -d: --output-delimiter=$'\n' -f1-
```

#### Edit

As noted by Chris below, this will leave a trailing newline, this can be avoided if your awk supports specifying `RS` as a regular expression (tested with GNU awk):

```
awk -v RS='[:\n]' 1
```

Comment: Your `awk` example will leave a (probably undesirable) trailing newline.

Comment: @ChrisDown: you're right, this can be avoided if RS can be a regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ line=foo:bar:baz:quux
$ words=$(IFS=:; set -- $line; printf "%s\n" "$@")
$ echo "$words"
foo
bar
baz
quux
```

Answer (score 4):

don't know why ppl hate on [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

```bsh
$ xargs --version | head -1
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.7.0
...
$ printf "foo:bar:baz:quux" | xargs -d: -n1
foo
bar
baz
quux
```

Answer (score 0):

##### A pure Bash solution that works with ':' at the end.

```
## Split string, store in array:
IFS=: read -ra arr <<< "$line:X"    # pad to prevent skipping an empty last field
unset "arr[ ${#arr[@]} - 1 ]"       # pop last element
```

##### Example

```
line=foo:bar:

## wrong:
IFS=: read -ra arr <<< "$line"      # common method
declare -p arr                      # output: ... '([0]="foo" [1]="bar")'

## correct:
IFS=: read -ra arr <<< "$line:X"    # pad at end to prevent skipping a last empty field
unset "arr[ ${#arr[@]} - 1 ]"       # pop last element
declare -p arr                      # output: ... '([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="")'

## output as records ####
for j in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$j"; done  # output is "foo\nbar\n\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

In some strings I had problem with solutions above.
But this worked for me:

```
echo $string | sed 's/\\n/ /g' | tr " " \\n
```

Comment: As written, this does not transform the OP example input.